# Laravel Eloquent returning model with all relations

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, relation, inertiajs

When I use User model to return the data I need it gave me list of objects with all the relations.
User Model

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
{
    use SoftDeletes, Authenticatable, Authorizable, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    public function getNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->last_name.' '.$this->first_name;
    }

    public function service(){
        return $this->BelongsTo(Service::class);
    }

    public function group(){
        return $this->BelongsTo(Group::class);
    }
}
```

```
public function getUser($id){
    return User::find($id);
}
```

How can i return only the user fields without the relation objects ?

PS: Am using laravel 8 + Vuejs + Inertia js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel does not return any relation if you do not ask for it... if you are not using [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and writing the desired relations, then you are not going to get the relations when you do `User::find($id);` as `find` is an alias of `$model->whereKey($id)->first($columns)`...

So it is not getting any relations... you have to explain more...

This is the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6c8371351a4d498eee273dbaa4a3b7182335a463/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L386-L392) so you can see what `find` means.